# Cann't execute my test if I add __intSum function to the beanshell postprocessor

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have written a regular expression (`regexpname`) in my thread which returns a number Ex: 10 and when I try to use the regular expression in the BeanShell postprocessor by adding `__intSum` function to add a number to the regular expression out put Ex: to add 4 to the regular expression out put i.e., 10 and store the result to a variable Ex: Total, using the following function:

```
{__intSum(4,${regexpname},Total}
```

upon trying to run my test, it stops immediately with the message

> "Jmeter: Uncaught exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For
>   input string: "${regexpname}".....".

Please let me know how to fix the issue:

Here is the code I have put in beanshell postprocessor:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("m/dd/yyyy"); // change it according to your Date format

Date originalDate = sdf.parse(vars.get("SigDate"));

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.setTime(originalDate); 

${__intSum(4,${regexpname},Total)}; 

cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, Total); // change it if you need to add something else

Date newDate = cal.getTime();
vars.put("newDepdate", sdf.format(newDate));

log.info("Original date: " + vars.get("SigDate"));
log.info("New date: " + vars.get("newDepdate"));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [Don't inline JMeter Functions and/or variables into scripts](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) as they can resolve into something which will cause script failure or inconsistent behaviour. Either use "Parameters" section or go for code-based equivalents
2. Don't use Beanshell test elements, [it is recommended to switch to JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for any form of scripting since JMeter 3.1](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
3. Your [date format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) looks flaky as `m` stands for "minutes in hour", if you need "month in year" - go for capital `M`
4. Actually you don't even need any scripting here as there is [__timeShift() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) since [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32) which can do what you need, the relevant syntax would be something like:

   [image: JMeter TimeShift Demo]

Answer (score -1):

Use `int Total = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("regexpname"))+4;` instead of `${__intSum(4,${regexpname},Total)};`  in your [beanshell pre processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor)

[image]

I have defined  `regexpname` as 10 in test plan so its adding 14 days and storing new date in `newDepdate`.

For more information on beanshell please follow [this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/4878/)

Please let me know if it helps..